# py2app compiled script with ffmpeg not working (mac)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, py2app

I'm currently experiencing a lot of difficulties getting ffmpeg-python to work when compiling my script with Py2App. The attached script works fine when run from the command line, as does the terminal version found in the application bundle. When double clicking the app though, it just gives me a popup with (the not very descriptive) "Error". I've tried all possible solutions found in related posts including compiling the script with the "--emulate-shell-environment" flag. So far no luck. 
Details: Python 2.7.16 | macOs 10.14.6 | Latest version of ffmpeg & py2app.

Appreciate the help!

Thanks, martijn

```
import ffmpeg

stream = ffmpeg.input('input.mp4')
stream = ffmpeg.filter(stream,'scale', 800, 450)
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, 'output2.mp4')
ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

Comment: Is this just a wrapper to the `ffmpeg` command-line tool? If it is make sure that ffmpeg gets executed. It outputs a "log" to stderr. Refer to it if the problem is ffmpeg. Alternatively, add the `-report` option (not sure how to do that with whatever you're using), and look at the resulting log file. It will be named like `ffmpeg-20200418-104421.log`.

Comment: Hi llogan, Thanks for your time. ffmpeg-python is indeed a binding for ffmpeg (https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python). I've added the -report flag, which works perfectly when running the script in terminal or when opening the Unix executable. Which makes sense, since the script then also converts the mp4. When double clicking the app it just gives me the "error" error without creating a log-file. Which makes me believe that ffmpeg isn't running. I've tried to force opening the terminal by compile the using the "--emulate-shell-environment" flag with py2app. No luck.

Comment: I don't know anything about ffmpeg-python, but it appears not to be an issue with `ffmpeg` itself. Hopefully that will help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solved it by executing the via a shell script. That worked. Reported the bug to the developer of the ffmpeg python biding.

Comment: Because you found a solution consider adding it as an answer.